# $\lim\limits_{x \to 0}{\frac{\cos x - \cos 2x}{1 - \cos x}}$

Tags: limits, alternative-proof, infinitesimals

### Exercise:

> $$\lim\limits_{x \to 0}{\frac{\cos x - \cos 2x}{1 - \cos x}}$$

---

I've posted my solution down below, however if there are more elegant approaches, feel free to include your own solutions.

Answer (score 4):

We have the double angle formula:

$$\cos(2x)=2\cos^2(x)-1$$

Thus, it follows that

$$\cos(x)-\cos(2x)=1+\cos(x)-2\cos^2(x)=(1-\cos(x))(2\cos(x)+1)$$

Thus, we find

$$\frac{\cos(x)-\cos(2x)}{1-\cos(x)}=2\cos(x)+1$$

So the limit is directly $3$.

Comment: Wow, this answer is Simply Beautiful! I just learned about equivalent infinitesimals, so I rushed to use my new knowledge instead of recalling my old. :)

Comment: @SirJony Haha, thanks.  I think that if you have time and are practicing limits, a good technique builder is to see how many ways you can solve the same limit, so you aren't confined to just one method.  By the way, you can make your "equivalence" more rigorous using Taylor polynomials with remainder formulas.

Comment: I haven't studied Taylor polynomials yet, but I'll keep it in mind for when I do.

Answer (score 1):

By applying L'Hospital's rule twice, one has
$$
\lim\limits_{x \to 0}{\frac{\cos x - \cos 2x}{1 - \cos x}}=\lim\limits_{x \to 0}{\frac{-\sin x +2 \sin 2x}{\sin x}}=\lim\limits_{x \to 0}{\frac{-\cos x +4 \cos 2x}{\cos x}}=\frac{-1+4}1=3.
$$

Answer (score 0):

### Step 1: find equivalent infinitesimals

Recall: $\lim\limits_{x \to 0}{\frac{\cos m - \cos n}{x^2}} = \frac{n^2 - m^2}{2}$. So: $\lim\limits_{x \to 0}{\frac{\cos x - \cos 2x}{x^2}} = \frac{2^2 - 1^2}{2} = \frac{3}{2}$. To make $RHS = 1$: $\lim\limits_{x \to 0}{\frac{\cos x - \cos 2x}{\frac{3}{2}x^2}} = 1$. Finally: $\cos x - \cos 2x \sim \frac{3}{2}x^2$.

Recall: $\lim\limits_{x \to 0}{\frac{1 - \cos x}{x^2}} = \frac{1}{2}$. To make $RHS = 1$: $\lim\limits_{x \to 0}{\frac{1 - \cos x}{\frac{1}{2}x^2}} = 1$. Finally: $1 - \cos x \sim \frac{1}{2}x^2$

---

### Step 2: replace with equivalent infinitesimals

$\lim\limits_{x \to 0}{\frac{\cos x - \cos 2x}{1 - \cos x}}$
$= \lim\limits_{x \to 0}{\frac{\frac{3}{2}x^2}{\frac{1}{2}x^2}}$
$= 3$

---

### Answer:

$$\lim\limits_{x \to 0}{\frac{\cos x - \cos 2x}{1 - \cos x}} = 3$$

Comment: @SirJony Fair enough. It was indeed a drastic comment, to say the least. I'll delete it shortly.

Answer (score 0):

$=\dfrac{\cos x - \cos 2x}{1-\cos x}$

$=\dfrac{2\sin \left( \frac{x+2x}{2}\right) \sin \left( \frac{2x-x}{2}\right) }{2\sin^2 \left( \frac{x}{2}\right)}$

$=\dfrac{\sin 3x/2}{x} . \dfrac{x}{\sin x/2}$

$=\left(3/2\right) . \frac{1}{\left( 1/2\right)}$

$=3$

Formulae involved--

$\cos A - \cos B = 2\sin \frac{A+B}{2} \sin \frac{B-A}{2}$

$\cos 2A = 1-2\sin^2 A$

$\lim\limits_{x\to 0} \dfrac {\sin ax}{x} =a$

Comment: Please use Mathjax, as described here: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt now is it okay now?

Comment: @Noddy -- Looks fine to me. (I'd personally make the fractions vertical instead of horizontal, but that's a small detail.)

Answer (score 0):

If we evaluate directly we get the fraction $\frac{0}{0}$. So using L'Hopital's rule:
$$
\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{\cos x - \cos 2x}{1-\cos x}
=
\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{-\sin x + 2\sin 2x}{\sin x}
$$

Now, if we evaluate directly once more, we get the fraction $\frac{0}{0}$. So we use L'Hopital again to get:

$$
\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{-\cos x + 4 \cos 2x}{\cos x}
$$

Which, when evaluated on $x=0$ yields: $$\frac{-1 + 4}{1} = 3$$

Comment: We may stop after one application of L'H if you recall that $$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin(x)}x=1$$